# Easy way to redirect to mobile version of site?

Tags: redirect

I would like an easy way of detecting mobile and redirecting it to mobile site. My website is coded in html.

Mobile version of site: https://example.com/mobile

Desktop version (to redirect to mobile if device is mobile): https://example.com/

Comment: you can look at the user agent of the incoming request header and based on that redirect the request.

Comment: I am experienced, but not with user agents yet.

Comment: you can add an if condition in your webserver, for example if you are using nginx you can do something like, `if ($http_user_agent ~* "mobile") {
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/mobile/$1 permanent;
} `

Comment: I can see how that would work, but I am not hosting it my self and I don't have access to nginx, so is there someway I can adapt this to something like htaccess?

Comment: You can always look at the header user agent on application level itself and redirect from application also.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Which framework your application is written? Flask, django, express etc? Then you can google how to extract user agent in that framework or by using some library.

Comment: I don't really have a framework, it was an html template.

Comment: I found this tutorial, but it is giving me a redirect loop on the one called "complete".

https://www.addontechnologies.net/knowledge-base/redirect-to-mobile-site-using-htaccess-file-redirect-rules-of-htaccess-files-for-mobile-device.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using this: https://www.addontechnologies.net/knowledge-base/redirect-to-mobile-site-using-htaccess-file-redirect-rules-of-htaccess-files-for-mobile-device.html

And switching the mobile site to a subdomain.